# syntax error in Python "full_path_include_patterns = {os.path.join(sync_dir, x) for x in include_patterns}"

Tags: python, ubuntu, centos

I am using dx-toolkit to upload some file to natera server.

dx_sync_directory.py.

```
print >> sys.stderr, "Getting files to upload..."

cur_time = int(time.time())
to_upload = []
full_path_include_patterns = {os.path.join(sync_dir, x) for x in include_patterns}

for pattern in full_path_include_patterns:
    full_path_include = glob.glob(pattern)
    for path in full_path_include:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
            for name in dirs + files:
                full_path = os.path.join(root, name)
                cur_mtime = os.path.getmtime(full_path)
                if cur_time - cur_mtime > min_age:
                    if (full_path not in log['files']) or (cur_mtime > log['files'][full_path]['mtime']):
                        to_upload.append(full_path)

return to_upload
```

I am working in php and don't know how to solve this python syntax error. The os I am using is centos. The error line is `full_path_include_patterns = {os.path.join(sync_dir, x) for x in include_patterns}`

The error shows as `Syntax error: invalid syntax`

Its running in ubuntu Os.

Please help.

Comment: Please show more of the surrounding code, at least. Also, it would be good to know the value of `include_patterns` right before that statement.

Comment: Could you paste the error log too ? Along with the values of `include_patterns` and `sync_dir`.

Comment: What Python version are you using? Set comprehensions were introduced in 2.7, if you're using a previous version you will get a syntax error.

Comment: @DanielRoseman You are correct. I changed my python version to 2.7 and its working fine. Thank you.